# How can I highlight elements in a matrix without overlapping the delimiters?

Tags: matrices, highlighting, delimiters

I used the code given by Kottwitz, and here is the result. Put another way, how can I adjust the position of the delimiters so that the highlights do not overlap them?

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the code that gives rise to the screenshot above.

Answer (score 2):

One can do that conveniently with `nicematrix`. It comes with the keys `margin` which allow one to avoid those overlaps, and `create-cell-nodes` which can be used to put the colored boxes in the background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{he/.code={\node[draw,rounded corners,fill=blue!20,inner sep=2pt,fit=#1]{};}}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,margin]
        \CodeBefore[create-cell-nodes]
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{he=(1-1)(1-3)}
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \Body
        0 & -1 & 1\\
        -2 & 2 & 0 
    \end{pNiceMatrix}    
    \cdot 
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,margin]
        \CodeBefore[create-cell-nodes]
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{he=(1-1)(3-1)}
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \Body
        -3 & 2 \\
        2 & 2\\ 
        0 & -1\\ 
    \end{pNiceMatrix}    
    =
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,margin]
        \CodeBefore[create-cell-nodes]
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{he=(1-1)}
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \Body
        C_{11} & C_{12} \\
        C_{21} & C_{22}\\ 
    \end{pNiceMatrix}    
\]    
\end{document}
```

[image]